# Pull random image from directory, encode to base64 and then print

Tags: python, random, base64, encode

I'm having difficult time trying to work these two together. It's frustrating me a little, so I hope to find ideas/solutions.

The complete works (what I'm planning on) should grab a random image from an online directory, encode it to base64 then print the base64. I've had total curl madness going all day and now I'm turning to python. Onwards!

These are kinda just notes at the minute but should explain the process.

```
import random, os
import base64

def search(): #get file
    path = r"/Users/Impshum/Pictures" #should be able to http
    random_filename = random.choice([
        x for x in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
    ])
    print(random_filename) #not printing full location


def encode(): #encode to base64
    image = open('heaven.jpg', 'rb')
    image_read = image.read()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
    print image_64_encode

search() #notes
encode() #notes
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What, other than "please write code for me', is the question here?

Comment: The structure is promising, although you might want to return something from `search` that you can pass as an argument to `encode`. `encode` should probably return the value too.. Maybe you even need a `read` function, so your main code would be `print encode(read(search()))`...

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the code you need

```
import random, os
import base64

def search(path): #get file
    random_filename = random.choice([
        x for x in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
    ])
    return os.path.join(path, random_filename)


def encode(path):
    image = open(path, 'rb')
    image_read = image.read()
    image.close()
    image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
    return image_64_encode

print(encode(search(r"/Users/Impshum/Pictures")))
```

There are things you can do to make this "nicer", but this should get you started.

For instance, you might want to use `glob` instead of os.listdir / os.path.join, etc.  And using a context manager

```
import glob
import base64
import random

def search(path): #get file
    random_filename = random.choice(glob.glob(path))
    return random_filename


def encode(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as image:
        image_read = image.read()
        image_64_encode = base64.encodestring(image_read)
        return image_64_encode

print(encode(search(r"/Users/Impshum/Pictures/*")))
```

Error handling is left as an exercise to the OP

Comment: Fantastic. Today will be a better day because of you.